# How to replace a number present in square brackets in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `//*[@id=\"yui-main\"]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]` in a for loop.

I need to replace `td[1]` to `td[i+1]` .

Tried many regex expressions .

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=td\[)1(?=\])
```

Try this.Replace by `i+1`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/5

This uses lookbehind to make sure `1` begin captured has `td[` behind it and a lookahead to ensure it has `]` ahead of it.